# Change MySite template

Tags: 2013, my-site, mysite, feature-stapling, mysites

When a user in SharePoint 2013 clicks on his name and 'about me' for the first time, a MySite will be created. What are the possibilities to change the template that is used to create this site (collection)?

I'm not a programmer, but I already read about feature stapling to brand the MySites including subsites. But I would like to change more than just masterpage and css. I have requirements like adding lists, pages, web parts and custom navigation to the MySite template.

My question is: is this possible? And if so, is this also done by the 'feature stapling method'? What are the limitations of this? etc.. Any advise is much aprreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you two blogs which I just read because I was planning to do the same as you are.

1. What is feature stapling and how to achieve it [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/feature-stapling-in-sharepoint/).
2. How to create a list with data whenever a site is created [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/626731/Feature-Stapling-in-Sharepoint).

Apart from that feature stapling is quite powerful, whatever can be done through feature object model, i.e. feature activation, deactivation can be done with feature stapling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible and can be done using feature stapling. Here is a good [Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/apply-custom-theme-to-sharepoint-2013-mysite-using-feature-stapling) to start learning on how to do that.

Feature receiver can be used along with Feature stapling which can add list, document library and web parts in the mysite page.

Here is good one [here](https://radutut.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/feature-stapling-and-site-provisioning-challenges/) specific to your need.

As long as you don't change the default template and go with feature stapling and feature receivers activated upon feature stapling then there is not much precaution and you could possibly add a lot of customization in the mysite page.